# use-package does not download packages

Tags: emacs, config

I don't quite get the use-package package. I thought of it as a replacement of the older require statement in config files but on github it [reads](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)

> This loads in the package XYZ, but only if XYZ is available on your system

So do I have to ensure that I have the package before?
Because sometimes it seems, all I need is the use-package statement for a fresh Emacs install to get the dependency.

Please clarify.

Comment: `use-package` is (at a very high level) basically like require; the package needs to be installed.  You can use `:ensure` to install the package (but don't `:ensure` builtin packages, at least that caused problems for me).  You can also use `use-package-always-ensure` to change the default of `:ensure`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* the point is to let you share your `init.el` across systems and simply have it ignore packages which are not available on any particular system.

It also appears to allow you to specify, but defer the evaluation of, your own customizations for any package you `use` until the package is actually loaded, so unlike `require`, it doesn't force you to load a package you are not going to use in this session.

There is a facility for requiring a package to be installed if it's not installed; look for the `:ensure` keyword and the `use-package-always-ensure` configuration variable in the [documentation.](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)